# Using the id of a separator page to define menu end

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have the following page structure:

```
toppage
-page1
-page2
-page3
-page4
- (menu separator)
-page5
-page6
-page7
-page8
```

Page1 to page4 are being used to define a horizontal main menu.

Page5 to page7 are being used to define a vertical side menu.

The following typoscript is being used for the main menu:

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu.special = directory
lib.mainMenu.special.value = {$main_menu_start_id}

lib.mainMenu.entryLevel = 0

lib.mainMenu.1 = TMENU
lib.mainMenu.1 {
  // Fix to limit items in main menu
  maxItems = 4
}
```

Is it possible in typoscript to replace the `maxItems` approach by something like the following?

- Get the pageid of the menu separator.
- Using a statement to say that mainMenu should end at this pageid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Risky approach, I doubt if it will be possible to do that with pure TypoScript

Instead I'd suggest to build horizontal menu (pages 1-4) with `special=list` example:

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu.special = list
lib.mainMenu.special.value = 1,2,3,4
lib.mainMenu.1 = TMENU
//etc
```

and then vertical menu as a menu of all other items except of the previous 4

```
lib.sideMenu = HMENU
lib.sideMenu.excludeUidList = 1,2,3,4
lib.sideMenu.1 = TMENU
// etc
```

**other way**

you can also put the page which is `hidden in menu` at the begining let's call it `horizontal menu items` and then use `special=directory` in `HMENU` to build menu with all sub-items. It's also easier add/delete/change items without changing the TS:

structure:

```
- horizontal menu items (uid: 123, hidden in menu)
  |-- page 1
  |-- page 2
  |-- page 3
  --- page 4
- page 5
- page 6
- page 7
```

TS:

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu.special = directory
lib.mainMenu.special.value = 123
lib.mainMenu.1 = TMENU
//etc


lib.sideMenu = HMENU
lib.sideMenu.1 = TMENU
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But you cannot use optionSplit then.

(untested)

```
lib.mainMenu.1.NO.allStdWrap {
  prepend = LOAD_REGISTER
  prepend {
    data = REGISTER:hideMenuItem
    ifEmpty = 0
    override = 1
    override.if.equals.field = doktype
    override.if.value = 199
  }
  if.isFalse.data = REGISTER:hideMenuItem
}
```

I did not tested, but the main princple should become clear: create an internal REGISTER which is checked for each menuitem. If there is an menu-item of doktype menu-separator (199) then set the register. If the register is set, do not render the menu.